# Why is Background Dark and not Blurred for Portrait Outdoor picture Cannon Zoom Lens 70 - 300 mm

Tags: background, canon-700d

The picture was taken at 1 pm, [image]
2.5MP
1920 × 1280
128.1 KB
Canon Canon EOS 700D
ƒ/5.6
1/160
270mm
ISO200

Answer (score 2):

Your background is blurred, but it is difficult to see because it is under exposed. You can use photo editing software to lighten the photo and bring out the details in the background.

[image]